# SQL Convert number to a word

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a simple SELECT query to get retrieve a set of item numbers from a SQL table.

now from this table, i want to get the Item type which can be one of three. `Make, Buy or undefined`.

My issue is that this is indicated in a number in the database. My table has a column called `ITMTYPE` but says `1 or 2 or 3 for Make, Buy or undefined`.

Could anyone advise me of a way to add a column to my select Query that can show the equivalent wording for Item Type please?

Below is what i'd like to see,

```
Item_Number Item_Type_Num   Item Type_val
A                1               Make
B                2               Buy
C                3               Undefined
D                2               Buy
E                1               Make
```

This third column is what i'd like to see.
Thanks

Comment: is ITMTYPE a foreign key? if not then the simplest would be to add a case statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple Case Expression.

```
select
    Item_Number,
    Item_Type_Num ,
    Case Item_Type_Num
       when 1 then 'Make'
       when 2 then 'Buy'
       when 3 then 'Undefined'
    else 'Unknown'
    end as 'Item_type_val'
from Yourtable
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`CASE EXPRESSION`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/case.php) :

```
SELECT t.Item_Number,t.ITMTYPE as Item_Type_Num,
       CASE WHEN t.ITMTYPE = 1 THEN 'Make'
            WHEN t.ITMTYPE = 2 THEN 'Buy'
            WHEN t.ITMTYPE = 3 THEN 'undefined'
       END as Item_Type_Val
FROM YourTable t
```

If you have daily needs with this column I'd suggest you add it to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
  ADD Item_Val_Type VARCHAR2(10);
```

And then update it:

```
UPDATE YourTable t
SET t.Item_Val_Type = CASE WHEN t.ITMTYPE = 1 THEN 'Make'
                           WHEN t.ITMTYPE = 2 THEN 'Buy'
                           WHEN t.ITMTYPE = 3 THEN 'undefined'
                      END;
```

Comment: If you're adding an extra column, SQL Server has computed columns - will never be inconsistent! (Or create a view instead.)

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE expression

   WHEN value_1 THEN result_1
   WHEN value_2 THEN result_2
   ...
   WHEN value_n THEN result_n

   ELSE result

END

select item_number
,case Item_Type_num
   when 1 then 'Make'
   when 2 then 'Buy'
   else 'Undefined
end
```